# LESS Browser Compiler Not working on Second Dev Machine

Tags: javascript, localhost, less, dropbox

I have two dev machines. My code is synced between the two with dropbox and I use MAMP as my hosting environment. I use a the LESS js browser compiler. Works good. When I go to the second dev machine everything works except for the less files. I can access them from the browser with direct links and the permissions seem identical in the working environment.

The only real variable I see is that I have my laptop (working environment) set up as localhost/ and my desktop (not working environment) as localhost.myusername/

Is there something in the less.js that needs a standardized url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - it is a matter of the localhost.myusername causing the problem. I will close this question but if anyone happens to know WHY that's the case, I'd love to hear your thoughts. :)